# Why is the definition of the absolute value $|x+1|$ the way it is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, absolute-value

In my notebook it is given that for the above function, we would have:

$f(x) = {-(x+1), x<-1; (x+1), x\geq-1}$

What I don't get is why did we take $-1$ instead of $0$ as is the case for the function $|x|$? Will the function change substantially if I use $0$ instead of $-1$?

Comment: What is the function "mod(x)"?

Comment: @MattSamuel I guess OP means $|x|$

Comment: @NeilRoy Yes! It is |x|.

Comment: You want $|x + 1| \geq 0$.  What happens if you use $0$ instead of $-1$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$|x| = \begin{cases} x &\mbox{if } x \geq 0 \\ 
-x & \mbox{if } x < 0. \end{cases}$$

The above function says that the function $|x|$ works by adding a minus sign whenever $x$ is negative, making $x$ overall positive and leaving $x$ as it is when $x \geq 0$. Now let's shift this function to the left by $1$ unit.

We get $$|x+1| = \begin{cases} x+1 &\mbox{if } x+1 \geq 0 \\ 
-(x+1) & \mbox{if } x+1 < 0. \end{cases}$$

But $x+1 \geq 0 \iff x \geq -1$ and similarly for $x+1 < 0 \iff x < -1$ so we can rewrite the above as $$|x+1| = \begin{cases} x+1 &\mbox{if } x \geq -1 \\ 
-(x+1) & \mbox{if } x < -1. \end{cases}$$

This says that whenever $x+1$ is positive, we leave $x+1$ as it is. But $x+1$ is positive as long as $x \geq -1$ However if $x+1$ is negative, then we tack on a minus sign to make it positive again. But $x+1$ is negative whenever $x<-1$.

You can see this from the graph of $|x+1|$ and $x+1$:

[image]

Comment: There are a couple of typographical errors.  After the piecewise definition of $|x + 1$, it should read "But $x + 1 \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow x \geq -\color{red}{1}$ ..." In the last sentence of the penultimate paragraph, it should read "But $x \color{red}{+} 1$ is negative whenever $x < -1$."

Comment: @N.F.Taussig, I corrected them, thanks! :-)

Comment: `Now let's shift this function to the right ` — you mean to the left...

Comment: @Ruslan, Yups! Corrected. I had thought the question was originally asking for $x-1$, hence the massive amount of typos as I went through at the end and corrected everything.